# Start a remote script from a Mac OS X machine via SSH command

Tags: python, linux, macos, unix, ssh

I am trying to start a python script on my VM from my local Mac OS

I did

```
ssh -i /key/path/id_rsa root@111.11.1.0 "sleep 5s; cd /root/Server;pkill -f server.py;./server.py;"
```

Result

It's SSH in and it quickly runs those commands and it quickly logging me out. I was expecting it to stay open in SSH session.

My script is **NOT** running ...

**ps -aux | grep python**

```
root       901  0.0  0.2 553164 18584 ?        Ssl  Jan19  20:37 /usr/bin/pytho -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
root     15444  0.0  0.0 112648   976 pts/0    S+   19:16   0:00 grep --color=auto python
```

---

If I do this it works

```
ssh -i /key/path/id_rsa root@111.11.1.0 "sleep 5s; cd /root/Server"
```

Then

```
./server.py;
```

Then, it works.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the contents of this server.py program?

Comment: What do you mean *"I was expecting it to stay open"*? Why would it do that? It has done everything you asked so the command is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to state the shell starting your script i.e `/bin/bash server.py`:

```
ssh -i /key/path/id_rsa root@111.11.1.0 "sleep 5s; cd /root/Server; pkill -f server.py; /bin/bash ./server.py;"
```

If you would like to start the script and leave it running even after you end your ssh session you could use `nohup`. Notice that you need to put the process in the background and redirect `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` to completly detach from the remote process:

```
-i /key/path/id_rsa root@111.11.1.0 "sleep 5s; cd /root/Server; nohup /bin/bash ./server.py < /dev/null > std.out 2> std.err &"
```

It seems like the reason that your ssh command returns imediately is because somehow the call to `pkill -f server.py` will also terminate the actual ssh session, since it also contains the `server.py` in the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my regular MacBook Pro here to test with, but I think that adding another semicolon and ending the command line with /bin/bash might do it.